# who can tell me the difference of folder between controller and controllers in the magento?

Tags: magento

Today, looking at background information on magento suddenly found app \ code \ core \ Mage \ Adminhtml folder with controller and controllers generally two folders we have created a module controller did not mention controllers folder file folder, I would like to know, controller and controllers difference between these two folders were for?

Answer (score 3):

Controller is a custom inheritance for Varien/Magento custom Zend_Controller implementation that will lead you to inherit , extend or rewrite abstract class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action methods

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.html
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento#3
- http://alanstorm.com/magento_base_directories